# How do I extract the row id column from Bayes predictor in KNIME?

Tags: knime

[image]

I have the following classified data from my naive Bayes predictor. I want to be able to export it into a excel file. I've tried using a a Excel writer node and also tried just copying and pasting the data, but both of them seem to ignore the row id column. Is there any way for me to write the row id column into a file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **RowID** node to create a new column (`Create new column with the RowID values`) (and a **Column Rearranger** node to move it to the first column).

Or just select the `add row ids` option in the **Excel Writer** node.